# Is there any type of Bootstrap fly out that overlays the website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a layout with a flyout div, very similar to the "Who Are You" tab on this page :http://www.fanshawec.ca/.

All the examples I've found either push the entire site when it slides or is on the wrong side of the screen, like this one: http://blog.themearmada.com/off-canvas-slide-menu-for-bootstrap/

Has anyone ever come across something like this for bootstrap?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you're down voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much need to just change all the right CSS positioning to left and the same with the transitions

So, anything like this

> ```
> right: ?;
> ```

becomes

```
left: ?;
```

and anything like this

> ```
> transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
> -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
> -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
> -o-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
> ```

becomes

```
transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
```

See the modified version of the code snipped (credit to http://blog.themearmada.com/off-canvas-slide-menu-for-bootstrap/ mentioned in your question) below. I've commented the changed lines in the CSS `/* changed ...`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){            
 
       //Navigation Menu Slider
        $('#nav-expander').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('nav-expanded');
       });
       $('#nav-close').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').removeClass('nav-expanded');
       });
 
       // Initialize navgoco with default options
        $(".main-menu").navgoco({
            caret: '<span class="caret"></span>',
            accordion: false,
            openClass: 'open',
            save: true,
            cookie: {
                name: 'navgoco',
                expires: false,
                path: '/'
            },
            slide: {
                duration: 300,
                easing: 'swing'
            }
        });
 
      });
```

```css
/* SECTION 1 */
a.nav-expander {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.6em 2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* changed */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;  /* changed */
  width: 130px;
  z-index: 12;
 
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;  /* changed for this and the 3 lines below */
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 
}
 
a.nav-expander:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
a.nav-expander.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
 
.nav-expanded a.nav-expander.fixed {
    left: 20em;  /* changed */
}

/* SECTION 2 */
nav {
  background: #2d2f33;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: -20em;  /* changed */
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 0;
  width: 20em;
  z-index: 2000;
 
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;  /* changed for this and the 3 lines below */
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 
}
.nav-expanded nav {
  left: 0; /* changed */
}
 
body.nav-expanded {
  margin-left: 0em;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;  /* changed for this and the 3 lines below */
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
 
#nav-close {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/* SECTION 3 */
.main-menu {
  padding-top: 12px;
}
 
.main-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #323949;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px;
}
 
.main-menu li a {
  color: #6F7D8C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.main-menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.main-menu li .sub-nav {
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
}
 
.main-menu a .caret {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 border-top: 4px solid #4f5963;
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
 content: "";
    margin-top: 8px;
}
 
.main-menu a:hover .caret {
 border-top-color: #4f5963;
}
 
.main-menu li.open > a > .caret {
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #4f5963;
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
 
.main-menu li.open > a:hover > .caret {
 border-bottom-color: #4f5963;
}
 
.icon:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  content: '\f105';
}
 
.main-menu li > a > span.icon {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.1em 1.7em -0.1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 
}
 
.main-menu li > a:hover > span.icon {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.1em 0.8em -0.1em 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="list-unstyled main-menu">
 
    <!--Include your navigation here-->
    <li class="text-right"><a href="#" id="nav-close">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu One <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Two <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Three <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Sub Menu One <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Sub Menu Two <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Sub Menu Three <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Sub Menu Four <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav"><a href="#">Sub Menu Five <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Four <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Five <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">      
 
    <!--Include your brand here-->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Off Canvas Menu</a>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <a id="nav-expander" class="nav-expander fixed">
        MENU &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg white"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```